# Parallel.For loop does not execute code after finished

Tags: c#, for-loop, parallel-processing, execution

After the Parallel.For loop is finished the code below the loop will not be executed. The return statement is not going to be executed even if i'll set a breakpoint the program does not reach it.
Do you have any ideas why?

Thank you

c is a canvas by the way.

Here is the code:

```
        Parallel.For(0, Playfield.Last().Field.GetLength(0), x => 
        {
            Parallel.For(0, Playfield.Last().Field.GetLength(1), y =>
            {
                if (Playfield.Last().Field[x, y] == 1)
                    {
                        c.Children.Add(createRectangle(lengthX, lengthY, x, y));
                    }
            });
        });

        return c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably get an exception on "c.Children.Add" because it's trying to add controls crossthreaded. Thats not allowed in wpf.

Comment: Yes, thank you I had disabled the common language runtime exceptions for testing purposes.